# Ethical Dilemma: Should I still cater for IE6 as a web-developer

Tags: png, internet-explorer-6, transparency

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [IE6: To support or not to support.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611/ie6-to-support-or-not-to-support)
>   [Should we support IE6 anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786/should-we-support-ie6-anymore)

I'd hate to (HATE TO) admit it, but there are some people still using this browser. A client of mine is facing an issue where the "transparency" area of a png comes out a light grey - ONLY on IE6.

I know it's an unsupported browser, but some people STILL use it. I'd love to have a little discussion about whether or not I should choose to support it.

One point pro-support of IE6 is that often in large organisations, the update of systems is often unimportant to their IT department, so theres a large proportion of people working in these organisations that still use IE6. Schools are the same.

One point con-support of IE6 is that Microsoft no longer offer support for it, and it is considered a defunct browser, so why should I waste my time catering for it.

It is a little bit of a dilemma. I'd love to hear other peoples responses to this.

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp  and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers . IE 6 is still about 10 %, while Google Chrome climbed to 16%. If your customer needs it, make him pay for the necessary adjustments. I mean we are talking about days of work here. If he doesn't, drop it and tell him to upgrade his MAJOR unfixed and unpatched security risks. And if he used IE6 for a longer time now, he should check for intruders/trojans as well. Though I would advise him to format the hard drive and change all passwords on all computers/servers/mailaccounts.

Comment: I'd also tell him to use Google Chrome instead of IE. Reason: http://acid3.acidtests.org

Comment: @Quandary, was any of that scare-mongering actually helpful, or indeed true? I think not. If you'd taken the time to read the answers and comments, you'd have noted that the OP is creating an externally facing website, so telling his client "use browser X instead" really won't wash when Joe Public will be the person actually accessing it.

Comment: @Quandary - It's painful every time someone links to w3cschools.com's stats. The audience for that site is 100% developers, and is wayyyy scewed.

Comment: @Quandary - W3Schools' stats are pretty biased toward non-IE browsers. Here's data from a few other sources: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers#Summary_table

Comment: @derekerdmann W3School's statistics are biased yes, but Wikipedia as an alternative?

Comment: @Daniel Hanly - The table I linked to has several different counters, with links to the original sources. Check the originals if you don't think the table's right.

Comment: @derekerdmann I'm not disputing the validity of the data, I'm disputing the fact that Wikipedia groups IE as a whole, we're talking about specifically IE6 here and if you look at the usage statistics and news reports, the general consensus is that there is currently less than 5% of users still using IE6. I do respect the fact that IE is THE most used browser, but if we're talking IE6 specifically then it's a whole different ball game

Comment: @Daniel Hanly - I know we're talking about IE6. Take a look at the top of the page; it does have a breakdown of IE versions below the chart on the right-hand side.  NetApplications claims IE6's usage share is a bit higher than what you'd expect.

Comment: Duplicate of MANY questions, including: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786/should-we-support-ie6-anymore http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611/ie6-to-support-or-not-to-support http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304305/do-you-plan-to-support-ie-6-on-your-future-projects http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049369/will-you-still-support-ie6-when-writing-webpages

Comment: @Rob: OK, I overread that it's not for a corporate users, so you can't really tell them which browser NOT to use. I disagree with fear mongering. Formatting the hard drive might not be necessary, but the fact is that security bugs in IE6 do not get fixed anymore, and known unfixed critical security bugs existed for more than a year already. I would not install IE6 on any computer with an inet connection anymore. I would instead focus on making the pages display properly in Chrome and IE7+, which is far more important and not really easy if it has to really work.

Comment: @Quandary. FUD. http://serverfault.com/questions/929/when-does-microsofts-ie6-support-expire

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> One point con-support of IE6 is that
>   Microsoft no longer offer support for
>   it, and it is considered a defunct
>   browser, so why should I waste my time
>   catering for it.

Because it's not Microsoft you're catering for, or people who consider it a defunct browser, it's people using the browser, aka your customers. By all means, don't take on customers who have a requirement that you support IE6 with websites you produce, that is your chocie. But if you're getting paid for it, I'd hardly call it "*wasting my time*" =)

Comment: Exactly. The worm has to taste the fish not the fisher...

Comment: I see what your saying but my client's website is outward facing, its her customers that I'll be catering for, not her alone - but thank you for helping me make my decision - I will now go and convert every png image on the website to a jpg. As much as I hate IE6 personally you've helped me realise it's not my opinion that counts. Cheers :)

Comment: @Daniel Hanly - Please don't convert your PNGs to JPEGs. It's only transparent PNGs which IE6 has an issue with and i believe that there are ways around that.

Comment: there are png-transparency hacks that work pretty good, no sense in ruining the site for everyone else just because ie6 is a piece of junk.

Comment: @grapefrukt - in that you have captured the essence of my original question :)

Comment: In the absence of a comment explaining the downvote, I'll assume that it's from one of the "OMGZ IE6 must die, no matter what the client wants, even if there are end users who *cannot* upgrade" crowd.

Comment: This is the answer from the UK government about a petition to update from IE6: http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2010/08/despite-petition-uk-government-to-keep-ie6.ars

Answer (score 8):

For my own sites I do not bother with being pixel perfect and having identical functionality in IE6 but I do like to make sure that the site is accessible and functional at a basic level. That shouldn't be too hard and it'll probably be useful for web crawlers as well.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see an alternative. In fact, I dare say it wasn't very professional of you to put a commercial site up that doesn't support IE6. Your site should work on all browsers - cross browser compatibly is part of our job.

In reply to the comments, here's what I mean when I say professional:

- It is expected of you to know IE6 is going to be a problem before you start.
- Target supported browsers ***must be part of the contract***. Before working on the site you should ask who will be the target crowd and make that decision together. If you need to support IE6 your cost estimation should be higher.
- It is expected of you to at least test the site or all browsers (yes, including IE6, knowing that it isn't quite dead yet - you don't have to like it though).
- IE6 doesn't support PNGs, has weird box model (so don't use width+padding), etc etc... Every time I consider using a PNG, I take a note - this wouldn't work in all browsers. You are expected to know that or find it in the test you've made.
- **Full disclosure** - the site doesn't look or behave exactly the same on all browsers? When you present the site, explain how and why, and how it will effect end users. This may sound silly, but if you don't have IE6 in your contract, your client may not be too savvy. Your client is going to find out eventually the site doesn't work on IE6 - most likely when the site breaks for of her friends or clients, making her look bad. That knowledge better come from you.

Comment: I disagree, we're speaking of eye-candy here, not of website functionality.

Comment: I disagree too, 90% of internet users use firefox or IE6+, if we support 90% of viewer base thats real good numbers because no matter what you do, you will never be able to support all the browsers in the world, you can check list of browsers at wiki, you will be amazed that most of sites do not support 50% of browsers in that list.

Comment: @nico - ugly gray blocks around the images are unacceptable - as a user, would you trust such a site?

Comment: @Akash - please review the link by Giles: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/08/will-the-real-browser-stats-please-stand-up/ - I just finished looking at it, and it doesn't look like less than 10% on all cases. Besides, 6% is quite a lot, isn't it?

Comment: Yes I saw the link, I still dont care much about it, as a business owner, I feel its too much cost to fight for 10% users without knowing are they worth spending time on it or not. Good paying customer will always understand problems and support you, otherwise the ones who will kill you for the money they pay you are the ones who dont upgrade.

Comment: @Kobi: As a user I want the site to work. If it's pretty that's better, but it's not the primary thing I look at. If I were a IE6 user I would see 95% of the web in a crappy way, so I'd be used to it. I agree with you that the site has to be USABLE, but then why don't you support IE5 then? If MS does not support IE6 anymore I don't see why you should.

Comment: @nico - I've added more text, explaining how I'd behave with a business customer.

Comment: @Kobi: Ok, much better with the new explanations :)

Comment: The only thing that puts me off websites, is when they use images instead of text, the images are very compressed and awful quality. I'm sorry but if every website had to support every version of every browser the internet would be stuck with just text and links. The fact is the more websites that don't support IE6, means the more people upgrade. Google should put a huge box on it's homepage if a user visits in IE6, telling them to upgrade.

Comment: @Jonathan - You are free to use *your own site* for such activism. I'd like IE6 to die as much as the next guy, but when you have a paying costumer, you can't decide that for him.

Comment: Not so long ago, many sites didn't render properly in firefox. This was sometimes due to developer laziness, but other times support for firefox was not considered cost effective by the business end (regardless of whether it really was cost effective or not). From a business perspective, ie6 should be supported (only) as long as it is cost effective to do so.

Comment: @Jonathan: Google is not supporting IE6 anymore, see link in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I agree, making web sites display correctly in IE6 is tiresome. Being a web developer for a multinational pharmaceutical company I would know, they are still required to use IE6.

But there's another point to this. If we, the web developers as a group, continous to cater for IE6 then the large organizations have no reason to upgrade. Are we then responsible for people using IE6?

At our firm we have decided not to support IE6 in the administration part of our CMS, but we do cater for IE6 to the public eye.

The client mentioned earlier runs an old version of our CMS and is so stuck there although we and the administrators are willing to upgrade. In other words: Stuck between a rock and a hard place.

Comment: If we, the web developers as a group, continous to cater for IE6 then the large organizations have no reason to upgrade. Are we then responsible for people using IE6?

I love the above quote! So philosophical :)

Comment: That's what I was going for, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Count yourself lucky you're not trying to cater for the Chinese internet user-base...

I make the site **work** in IE6, but have a banner that comes down pleading with the user to upgrade to experience the awesomeness of this century.

[Example page that shows the banner](http://3540-blog.ecpod.com/)

Comment: Wow, I'm sure my boss would hang me but perhaps an idea to hide in the site haha. I'd love to see a link to that if you have one :)

Dan

Comment: I wonder why Firefox, Chrome and Opera neglected this market. After all this is the country that has highest number of internet users.

Comment: I've noticed a huge difference in the amount of 'MS' programmers there as well, and relatively few open source users. Our Chinese partner company has about 5 devs, only one knows any PHP. He started learning it 2 weeks before I met him. Don't know about the others browsers, but FF has a Chinese version customized (complete with red, and a horrible Chinese style home page) for that market. In-laws love it. In case you didn't know, the Chinese use even worse browsers than IE6 - http://tt.qq.com/ IT IS HORRIBLE. To be honest I have a hunch it's based on licensed or reverse engineered IE code.

Answer (score 3):

It depends who you expect to use the website.

Some recent figures for use of [IE6 in different places](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/08/will-the-real-browser-stats-please-stand-up/)  make interested reading.

If your client still uses IE6, then you are probably going to have to give in (or convince them of their evil ways). Otherwise it might be worth explaining the numbers involved and the additional cost to cater to them - if it takes x hours of your time, does your client really want to pay for that?

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's made an interesting read. Perhaps a large point is this: http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/browser_stats/statcounter-china.jpg

China still uses IE6 regularly however, in Europe and US (my clients main customer base):

http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/browser_stats/statcounter-europe.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your user base and would need to be agreed with your client.  For an intranet type application you may be able to avoid it.  For public applications - government, banking websites, anything the public may rely on, you need to consider it still.

For more luxury type sites, e.g. 'brochure-ware' for a small business, you may be able to take a call on this, but again depends on your client's requirements - do they want to potentially turn away some business?  If you can make it fail gracefully (i.e. still looks ok in IE6, but with less bells and whistles), then you have more chance of selling this.

Comment: Some of my content is "bells and whistles" style content, so really the question could be, is it financially viable for my client to pay extra for an IE6 compatible version of the website. Thankfully the IE6 "damage" is minimal and I should be able to get away with just a few image changes.

Comment: That's a question for your client to consider.  If you can present the extra cost for the IE6 compatible, vs the typical usage figures for each browser (preferably broken down by demographics - their target audience may be more or less likely to be IE6 users), then they can take the business decision about how far they want to go to reach that user base.

Comment: Thanks for your input, it's very valuable

Answer (score 2):

My opinion is that the site has to be USABLE.

Eye-candy is good, and should be given to as many users as possible but, the question is: does the gray background of the image render the site impossible to use?

Supposing you have a substantial IE6 user base, are these users really complaining about that?
Or do you have 1 person out of the 100 that use IE6 complaining?

Now people say that the clients pay and you have to do what they say etc etc... Well, it's YOUR role to TEACH the client why IE6 should NOT be supported anymore.

Show them that:

1) the site WORKS (i.e. you can read content, submit forms etc), so the IE6 users will be able to use it

2) you can put some "hints" like "you have a crappy browser, don't complain if websites suck with that" (maybe in a slightly more polite way)

3) show them that even Internet giants [dropped support](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2010/01/modern-browsers-for-modern-applications.html) for IE6. Why should you keep it? Do you really want to live in the past?

Answer (score 1):

How much money do you earn from the customers who still use IE6?

How much resistance is there within those companies to upgrade from IE6?

How much money will it cost you to support IE6?

Answer (score 1):

We are software developers. We make tools to make life easier for people ("users").

If a user of your software is using IE6, and you refuse to offer that user support until he/she upgrades to a newer web browser, are you making life easier or harder for them?

I'm actually not asking this question rhetorically, believe it or not. It may be that for you to support an older browser takes away too much of your time, keeping you from developing features that would be of greater benefit to the user.

My point is that you need to ask yourself what is best for the user, not whether catering to someone who's using an old version of a piece of software (who isn't?) is somehow beneath you.

Comment: one of my issues is that it also has some very real security "holes" and it would be of benefit to the user to upgrade, but am I really the one who should be telling her that? I will support it, but I wont enjoy it haha

Comment: If they choose to leave your site because it doesn't work, you're making life harder on them. If they choose to upgrade their browser because it doesn't work, you're making their life better, because IE6 sucks. The problem is, it's not up to you, it's up to the visitor. Support IE6 with the bare minimum.

Comment: @Andrew: I totally agree. I would just emphasize again that this is where the thinking needs to be: on the user's needs. If a developer decides not to support IE6, it should be with a clear explanation to the user why this will ultimately be for the best -- NOT because he/she simply hates IE6 or because it's old or because Microsoft is evil.

Answer (score 1):

I like this approach: http://morten.dk/blog/ie6-tax-now

Normally I would say that IE6 and IE7 is not supported by default, but the client can pay an extra price for supporting legacy browsers (the website will cost 30-50% more depending on the website requirements).

It might be also a good idea to get information from similar sites. One of our newest deployed site has 2-3% IE visitors (including all IE versions), and the IE6 and IE7 users are below 1%. So we decided not to support IE 6 and 7 at all (we don't test them), and we give full functional support for IE 8 (the site is usable, and looks OK, but it isn't as sexy as in a modern browser with a better CSS3 support, which means that there aren't any gradients or rounded elements). But this site is a little special case.

So I say that analyze what kind of people will visit your site, and make a decision based on that information.

Answer (score 1):

I've never understood the idea that this is some sort of "ethical" issue.

If it's around a client then it's a commercial issue.

If your contract says that the site you've developed will support IE6.0 then yes, you should support it.

If it doesn't it's up to him to work out whether he wishes to pay you more to fix any issues that come up with it.

(If it's not specified then you need to make sure you specify it in your next contract otherwise you're open to requests to support anything your client fancies).

In terms of whether it's worth him supporting it, it will depend on his market.  I previously worked for a travel firm whose core client base was people who were aged 40+ which 12 months ago was still registering 30 - 40% IE6.0 usage.  In that instance IE6.0 support for their site is critical but obviously each site has a different user demographic and that will dictate your approach.

But an approach based on "principal" is unlikely to be the right way to go, you need to have specific commercial or technical issues which mean that the cost of supporting the browser is greater than the cost of not supporting it.

Comment: I consider it ethical in the sense that should I alienate those percentage of users (currently below 5%) just to save myself some time or to save the client some money? Or should I just do what I can to get the user to upgrade through web-prompts? It's ethical because it involves segregating the userbase. I admit, it's not traditionally ethical (whether to treat an obese patient etc.) but it still has some ethical standing

Comment: My point is really that the decision, ethical or not, isn't yours, it's the customers.  You should inform the client of the facts, potentially make a recommendation and then allow them to make the decision.  Developers hate IE6 for technical reasons but businesses don't make decision on those grounds and it's their customers who are potentially being turned away and I don't believe that a developer really has the understanding of the business or the authority to make that call.  Possibly you should consider the ethics of making decisions about someone else's business rather than asking them?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great discussion. My customers are car dealers and while IE6 useage is declining, it is still 12.5% of my traffic. I have actually seen PC's running Win98 in these stores. Amazing!

We've segmented our catalog product into different interfaces for them to pick from. We're getting ready to launch a new one and we're close to making the decision that it will not support IE6. They can still choose one of the others that still do, and we will continue to support those but not enhance them.

So I can *finally* embrace sprites and transparencies and ... :)

Comment: I think so far in this discussion it can be gleaned that there is an overwhelming responsibility to support IE6 for those so-called Computer Dinosaurs, and for those who have no control i.e. users in large organisations (system administrators control etc.) and while we as web developers may not WANT to support it, we have a duty to our clients to support it.

There also needs a clarification of what constitutes support. Support is not about look and feel, it's about same/alternative functionalities and it really doesn't matter what the look and feel is.

Comment: @Daniel - In our case it is all about look and feel. It's amazing - this is a consumer-facing site to help dealers sell accessories - why they would use anything but the nicest equipment to make the best impression is beyond me, but they regularly present accessories to customers on ancient, yellowing 15" monitors. If they can't make a sale they blame the catalog. Us.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a horse drink the water, but you can sure as hell lead him to it. What's the point of going forward in browser technology with advanced engines like Webkit and Gecko, if we still allow stupid, uninformed users to visit our websites in **IE6** without any interruption?

Then all web standards are redundant and we can just go ahead and make browser-specific websites, which ultimately will become online applications. I would say, educate your user, after all, if you don't, who is going to do it?

We have made a conscious decision here at our design studio to alert IE6 browser-users that their browser is too old and that they should upgrade. We have not encountered any problems so far.

One should take into account that if you are hired to develop specific IE6 web applications, then you really don't have a choice in the matter, but if you are part of a design studio developing forward moving websites implementing new technologies or advanced Javascript, then I would say forget about IE6.

After all, the internet is full web developer handiwork and if we decide it's over, then the revolution **will** come.

// *edit*

If you want to make stuff a little easier for yourself, using CSS, start using [BrowserDetect.js](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/CSS-Browser-detection-using-jQuery-instead-of-hacks.aspx) CSS browser detection. It's initialised using jQuery and simply adds a browser-specific class to your body tag on load.

In other words, if you're running Safari 5, your body tag will look like this:

`<body class="browserSafari browserSafari5">`

This enables you to create browser specific CSS styles without any hacking of sorts.

That was my last 2c.

Comment: A valid point. Maybe next time I'll make sure we specify not to support IE6, but as nothing was said this time around I feel I have to :(

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see this point anywhere above, but I apologize if I missed it.

It's interesting that you say ethical, because I think moving standards for technology forward is one of those responsibilities that we have as consumers and as developers. Moving towards SVG and HTML5 and CSS3 is really good for the industry, because it means more efficiency and a better, faster web.

It may not be best for the client if their site doesn't support IE6, but if developers move on from outdated technologies  *en masse*, it forces the last users of those technologies - in this case, businesses and schools and stegosauri with IE6 - to update their browsers, which is not a negative thing. **It's OK to make decisions for the good of the industry as a whole, and we should more often.**

Comment: Even when it will have a negative impact on the business of the person paying him?

Comment: I find it astonishing that when asked about what to do from an ethical perspective people consider the "right" thing to be to do a job which works against the interests of the person paying him.

Comment: @Jon Hopkins - Why is that astonishing? If a client was paying me to set up a spam email server or something equally illicit, it would be the right thing to go against his interests. Obviously this is more nuanced, but you can't expect the client's interests to be perfectly aligned with the interests of the industry 100% of the time.

Comment: No, if you don't like the job as it's offered you don't take it.  It's immoral to take a job and then not do what you'd agreed to do (and likely a breach of contract too).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends who will be using your app! If your client is the UK gov, then yes, you had better develop for IE6 as it's the only browser in use (due to legacy systems that will ONLY work in IE6)

If on the other hand your client all use Safari, then no you don't have to bother.

Comment: The website is for my client, so it's her customer base, and therefore potentially everyone on the planet. I've decided to support it, but I will do it begrudgingly :)

Answer (score 0):

Users will not stop using IE6 if all websites still work perfectly with it as they then have no reason to change.

This is bit of a "deadlock" which can only be broken if applications stop supporting IE6

Make the users aware that they are using an unsafe and out-dated software, e.g. with something like:

> This webpage will not work (well)
>   with IE6 because that browser is
>   insecure and no longer supported

Most of the time you can also convince the customer by explicitely stating how much it will cost to support and maintain the application for an unsupported browser. This will usually be a significant amout for any non-trivial website...

Answer (score 0):

The question really is how much degradation do we make IE6 users tolerate? My feeling is: quite a bit. I'd much rather this minority took the pain instead of holding back everybody else. Since our sites are all (naturally) semantically marked up and pass accessibility guidelines, they will make sense and work just fine with styles and javascript disabled. So the simple answer is to give IE6 users the old Netscape 4 treatment and disable all CSS and js for them.

Answer (score -1):

I would definately suggest customer to upgrade with following points.

Technically no updates are provided by Microsoft for IE6, if they do not upgrade their browser, they should be made aware of all security issues they have left open by not upgrading, such mild threats do work and its right as well. Plus you can certainly recommend firefox, as Microsoft never completely implemented html standard and in large organizations, standard, compliance and security these are always considered as big things and you can certainly point towards them and get your update done.

Comment: My client's website has a potentially unlimited customer base, my difficulty is that I cannot tell everyone globally that they must upgrade. Or do I put a message on there such as "This website works best in IE7, IE8, Chrome, Opera, Firefox, and hell, even Netscape Navigator legacy"

Comment: Yes, you can certainly put a message like that and it will certainly help, if you are talking about customer base, based on http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php, only 6.14% people are using IE6, and if you are supporting more then 90% of viewer base, thats good enough. With changes in technologies, we can never support 100%, you have to now add safari as a big time used on iphone and webkit on android.

Comment: comment for down vote??? are you afraid to put any?

Comment: Downvote comment:  There are two customers here - the company the site is being developed for and the the end user - the customer from the questioners point of view, the person he should try to make happy, is the company.  The company is not in the business of getting people to upgrade their browser, it's in the business of selling stuff.  Getting the customer to upgrade their browser involves the customer leaving the site (to get the new browser) which reduces the chance of them buying stuff.  You've got to do what's right by the person paying you and they gain nothing by pushing an upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

No.

I have a client that requires for his pages to work in Netscape Navigator because he uses it.

That doesn't mean that I should prepare all my pages for last historical version Netscape Navigator.