# Should I support IE6?

Tags: internet-explorer-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ethical Dilemma: Should I still cater for IE6 as a web-developer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520422/ethical-dilemma-should-i-still-cater-for-ie6-as-a-web-developer)

5% of IE users last month use IE6.  So I am curious if people think I should support it....because I haven't been.

http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: I wouldn't..Its not worth your time and effort for 5%.

Comment: It depends on your target audience. Are you creating a corporate application that depends on users that have a different set of browsers? If you're writing a general consumer web app, I wouldn't bother with IE6

Comment: @bizness, Why do you think this was downvoted? I see 0 up and 0 down...

Comment: That's 5% for what, visiting w3schools? It's likely that those numbers don't reflect the general population's numbers.

Comment: Along with jball's comment: there is not a site on the planet that can give you real world browser usage percentages... except your own.

Comment: Case in point, [Net Applications](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2) has IE 6 at just shy of 15%.

Comment: Megadupe (is that a word?).  Searching here for the exact question led to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520422/ethical-dilemma-should-i-still-cater-for-ie6-as-a-web-developer-closed which was closed as an exact dupe of 2 others, and it's not hard to find others

Comment: @Ken: Yes, I see that word used all the time.  ;)

Comment: Should your site be *usable* on IE6? Yes, absolutely. An accessibly-authored web site should *work* anywhere, even on a text-mode browser with no JavaScript. Should you spend a lot of time working around around IE6's shortcomings to get a page that looks as shiny and perfect as it does in other browsers? Well, that's another matter, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't..Its not worth your time and effort for 5%.

Answer (score 3):

No.  But someone is going to say you will lose customers if you don't.

It's time for IE6 to die, already.  Those of you who are still using tube monitors and abacuses, please give us a break and come into the 21st century.

As Bobince points out in his comment above, it's unrealistic to put a coat of wax on a VW Beetle, and expect it to look more like a Porsche.

Comment: +1 for `t's time for IE6 to die, already.`

Answer (score 3):

- What is your product or service?
- What percentage of conversions come
  from that 5% of ie users?
- What       percentage would come from
  those       users if your site had
  better support    for their
  browser?

If you answer those questions, you won't have to ask anybody else whether you should support IE6 for your site or not.

Answer (score 2):

Businesses tend to keep IE6 on as legacy applications might only support IE6 so you tend to find they are in no hurry to roll out newer versions of IE as they would have to update in-house applications.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not, but if your consumers consist of people that use old browsers, it might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that they're 5% of your user base, they're 5% of your IE user base. In otherwords, IE6 accounts for 5% of 30% of your traffic.

I would say no, because you'd be sacrificing too much time and features for too few people. That and big websites like youtube and firefox have dropped support already.

Answer (score 1):

IE6 users are almost exclusively corporate users whose update schedule is mandated by the corp. If your userbase is the general public then that 5% figure will be *much* lower and as such I dont think supporting IE6 is worthwhile.