# Supporting IE5&6: Still necessary?

Tags: browser, cross-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I support IE6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090874/should-i-support-ie6)

Supporting old browsers like IE5 and IE6 is a painful task. Debates about whether supporting IE5&6 or not are hot. I wonder how many users are still using IE5 or 6, and what's the market share of IE5&IE6?
Our team is developing a website that requires a large user base. For now we just aim to random users in the United States. We tried to run our website on an IE6 and it looked awful.Being kind of lazy, I want to know if it's necessary to support IE5&6.

Comment: I think supporting IE4 is also absolutely required.

Answer (score 3):

I'd poll your users (or keep track of their browser preferences with your web server).

I would guess that IE5 has zero users by now, and the percentage of IE6 users is small.  If both of these statements are true, then you have to ask yourself how risky it is to neglect that minority population.

Comment: +1 very easy to see in the course of a week/month how many users of IE5/IE6 you still have.

Comment: Not only IE5/IE6 but also IE4.